# Adding a 3D camera to a robot arm(ur5) in URDF for Rviz and Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, urdf, 3dcamera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am following boor Mastering ROS for Robotics Programmin and I am trying to add a 3D camera above my UR5 arm in urdf. But after I modified the ur5.urdf.xacro file by adding <xacro:include filename="$(find ur_description)/urdf/sensors/xtion_pro_live.urdf.xacro"/>. Thank you so much!!!!

[Please find the details of my problem with this link](https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros/issues/37)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301164/adding-a-3d-camera-to-a-robot-arm(ur5)-in-urdf-for-rviz-and-gazebo/) by [stevensu1838](https://answers.ros.org/users/32486/stevensu1838/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2018-08-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-08-26**:
After you modified the file, then what? Your sentence isn't complete. Please make this question complete, too (don't just link to the question on another site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. If you don't see any camera stream from gazebo, it probably does not know the camera exists.

Does your xacro file define the gazebo sensor somewhere, as described in [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_depth_camera&cat=connect_ros)? The macro you are using might not contain this part.

If that is the case, one way to fix it is to include another file in your main URDF file, with content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot>
  <gazebo reference="your_camera_link">
    <sensor type="depth" name="your_camera">       
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>             
      <camera>
          <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
          <image>
              <width>640</width>
              <height>480</height>
              <format>R8G8B8</format>
          </image>
          <depth_camera>

          </depth_camera>
          <clip>
              <near>0.1</near>
              <far>100</far>
          </clip>
      </camera>
      <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
          <baseline>0.2</baseline>
          <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
              <updateRate>10.0</updateRate>
              <cameraName>your_camera</cameraName>
              <frameName>your_camera_link</frameName>                   
          <imageTopicName>rgb/image_raw</imageTopicName>
          <depthImageTopicName>depth/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
          <pointCloudTopicName>depth/points</pointCloudTopicName>
          <cameraInfoTopicName>rgb/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>              
          <depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>depth/camera_info</depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>            
          <pointCloudCutoff>0.4</pointCloudCutoff>                
              <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
              <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
              <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
              <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
              <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
              <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
          <CxPrime>0.0</CxPrime>
          <Cx>0.0</Cx>
          <Cy>0.0</Cy>
          <focalLength>0.0</focalLength>
          </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

2. You should not change the robot macro file directly, since that is supplied by the robot manufacturer. If you want to attach a camera to the robot, just add the link+joint outside of the macro.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2018-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-27**:\

> You should not change the robot macro file directly, since that is supplied by the robot manufacturer. If you want to attach a camera to the robot, just add the link+joint outside of the macro.

I cannot upvote this enough ..

**Comment by [Ksen](https://answers.ros.org/users/24175/ksen/) on 2018-10-02**:
Can anyone explain this part more:
"You should not change the robot macro file directly, since that is supplied by the robot manufacturer. If you want to attach a camera to the robot, just add the link+joint outside of the macro."
Does this mean having separate files for the models?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-02**:\

> Does this mean having separate files for the models?

@Ksen: yes, that does imply that you'd have separate files for all models involved, *plus* a top-level file that combines them all (ie: imports and then calls the xacro macros).

**Comment by [Ksen](https://answers.ros.org/users/24175/ksen/) on 2018-10-02**:
Thanks a lot!